# React native base tab styling

Tags: native-base

I am working an react native application. I am using native base tab for tab navigation. It's working perfectly but this tab is plane and simple. I want this tab styling like google chrome tab. So how can style native base tab like chrome tab?? help please ...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the Native Base Customizer tool and download the theme: https://nativebase.io/customizer/

Read the section Customize of documentation for more informations and others ways : https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#Customize

Answer (score 0):

use this in native base tab and styling on and text

```
<Tab heading={<TabHeading><Image ..../><Text>Text</Text></TabHeading>}
```